# Haskell function to swap every second element in a list

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I'd like to know how to swap every second element of a list in Haskell.

Example output should look like this:

```
swap [1,2,3,4,5]  
[2,1,4,3,5]
```

What I have so far is

```
swap :: [a] -> [a]  
swap [] = []  
swap (x:xs) = head xs : [x]
```

but this only swaps the first two elements and any attempt I make to make the function recursive causes errors when I try to load the file that contains the function. How to make it recursive?

Comment: How about showing your attempts and the errors it causes?

Comment: What I was trying to do was swap (x:xs) = head xs : [x] swap xs . The error when trying to load file is "haskell.hs:3:25:
    The function `[x]' is applied to two arguments,
    but its type `[a]' has none
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `[x] swap xs'
    In the expression: head xs : [x] swap xs
    In an equation for `swap': swap (x : xs) = head xs : [x] swap xs
Failed, modules loaded: none."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to grab out 2 elements at a time:

```
swap [] = []
swap (x:y:rest) = y:x:(swap rest)
swap [x] = [x]
```

The last line is needed to allow odd-length lists -- it matches a list having length exactly 1, so it doesn't overlap either of the other 2 cases (length 0, and length 2 or more).

Comment: The empty and one-element patterns could be more concisely expressed as just `swap other = other` after the `(x:y:rest)` case.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've figured out how to make your code work for odd-sized lists by adding in swap [x] = [x]

Comment: @Chuck: True, but then you have to put that case last, because it overlaps the other case.  I feel more comfortable when the cases are disjoint, since then they can be in any order (maybe that's poor style though?)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Unfortunately, my Arbiter of Style hat is at the cleaners, but personally, I value concision over "ability to randomly reorder lines and have it work." It's very normal in Haskell code to have a catchall after your normal cases, so I don't think it would throw anyone off.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other quite excellent replies, here is a solution that uses some very handy libraries. First, install [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split), which provides many very nice ways of splitting up a list. Our strategy for this problem will be to first split your list into chunks of size two, then swap each chunk, then concatenate the result back into a flat list. Here's how the key function works:

```
Prelude Data.List.Split> chunk 2 [1..11]
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11]]
```

To swap the elements of each chunk, we can simply call `reverse`. So the final result is:

```
Prelude Data.List.Split> let swap = concat . map reverse . chunk 2
Prelude Data.List.Split> swap [1..5]
[2,1,4,3,5]
```

Answer (score 2):

@j_random_hacker's solution is better, however, if you want to see your implementation to completion, you could try this:

```
swap [] = []
swap (x:[]) = [x]
swap (x:xs) = head xs : x : (swap $ tail xs)
```

Notice however, the use of `head` and `tail` are unnecessary, and pattern matching can make things much cleaner here.

Answer (score 2):

```
import Data.Function(on)

swap = map snd . concatMap reverse . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . zip (cycle "aabb")
```

Don't take my solution too serious, I'm just trying to improve my Haskell-Foo...